# What is the most efficient way to populate class attributes with a row from a database query?

Tags: python, pylons, mysql

Looking to have a database query set all the instance variables in a class:

Example:

```
def populate(self, if):
    #Perform mysql query

    self._name = row['name']
    self._email = row['email']
    ...
```

What's the fastest way to do this?  Or is this not recommended (with a better approach)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It makes your code the most readable and predictable to do it manually like this. That way you know exactly what attributes exist and what attributes do not pretty easily.
- You can use `setattr` to automate tons of these.

  One fairly nice way would be  to define a list `attributes = ['name', 'email'...]` as a class attribute then to do

  ```
  for name in self.attributes:
      setattr(self, "_" + name, row[name])
  ```

  You also can get the attributes from the query itself, but this will change depending on your query (especially if you're using `SELECT *` or anything like that) and your changing your database.
- I notice these attributes all have leading underscore. If this is a purely internal thing, consider whether an attribute rather than the query result itself or storing a dict wouldn't better suit your needs. Generally, attributes are supposed to be fairly static things.
- I hear oursql is nicer the MySQLdb

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  This was very helpful.  What do you mean by your second to last point about the query result itself a dict?  Do you mean setting an instance variable like "info" and just setting the entire row equal to that?
row = db.getRow(query)
self._info = row
something like that?

Comment: @ensnare, That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Would it be weird to have a discrepancy in that case between user.id and user.info.id?  What is a cleaner solution?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may or may not also want to set all the other stuff directly as attributes. If you opened a new question explaining the problem you are solving, someone might be able to help you be sure you have the optimal design for your class.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) it's the most popular database abstraction for python.
If you really like the active record pattern there is a layer you can put on top of it called [elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki).

I use sqlalchemy because it's a nice database abstraction and allows me to switch out databases.  I use sqlite in memory for my tests and I can wedge it in to my code using sqlalchemy.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I used sqlalchemy for a bit, but since I'm not interested in database portability it seemed a little heavyweight for what I was trying to do.